# Creating security-scoped bookmark for hosts file

Tags: macos, bookmarks, entitlements, nsopenpanel, code-signing-entitlements

I am trying to create a security-scoped bookmark for the user's hosts file so that my app can access and modify it across launches. I'm getting the following error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file “hosts” couldn’t be
>   opened." UserInfo=0x10011e9f0
>   {NSURL=file://localhost/private/etc/hosts}

My entitlements file:

```
<key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.files.bookmarks.app-scope</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
<true/>
```

And the relevant code for creating the bookmark:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
    NSOpenPanel *openPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    [openPanel setDirectoryURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/private/etc/hosts"]];

    [openPanel beginSheetModalForWindow:[self window]
                      completionHandler:^(NSInteger result){

                          if (result == NSOKButton)
                          {
                              [self saveBookmarkFromURL:[openPanel URL]];
                          }else{
                              printf("YOU MUST SELECT A FILE");
                          }

                      }
     ];
}

- (void)saveBookmarkFromURL:(NSURL *)aURL
{
    NSError *error;
    bookmarkData = [aURL
            bookmarkDataWithOptions:NSURLBookmarkCreationWithSecurityScope
            includingResourceValuesForKeys:nil
            relativeToURL:nil
            error:&error];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
        printf("\nERROR CREATING BOOKMARK DATA");
    } else {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:bookmarkData forKey:@"bookmark"];
        printf("\nBOOKMARK DATA SAVED TO PREF FILE");
    }
}
```

Comment: I've recently come across a similar issue. I rebooted the computer and the issue was gone. I guess some nasty bug in OS X... Has rebooting the computer helped?

Comment: At which point exactly is the error logged? When stepping with the debugger, you should be able to see if it's because of the NSOpenPanel or because of the bookmarks creation (or something else later on).